# Map Generation for browser based games

Tags: html, canvas, dictionary, hex

I am building a browser-based game and I would like to generate a hex map. I have seen it done using Flash and I thought that it can be done using HTML5 canvas. I have done some research on it and I would like some suggestions from other experts on this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting basic algorithms like this from Flash to Canvas is actually not that difficult. If you need a canvas framework that's close to the AS3/Flash you can take a look at EaselJS: http://createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

Here's an article on Hexagon Tiles:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/04/16/understanding-hexagonal-tiles/